# Cron job won't process require_once

Tags: php, cron, require-once

I have a Cron job setup to run every 5min.  The Cron job is as follows:

```
php /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/Mail-test/index.php
```

At the end of my index.php script is the following:

```
$path = $base_path . trim($row['company']) . '/Users/' . trim($row['name']) . '/Upload/';
$zip_processing_file = $path . 'zip.php';

require_once "zip_processing_file";
```

However when the Cron job is run, I get an error stating that the following directory which `= $zip_processing_file` does not exist in `/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/Mail-test/`

I can't seem to figure out this problem.  I have tried include but that gives the same problem.  Only way I got this to work is by putting

```
header("location: $zip_processing_file");
```

and then hitting `Mail-test/index.php` from a web browser, then it will cycle through the whole process, but I can't do it through a web browser, I need the Cron job to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error message that mentions */var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/Mail-test/* doesn't seem to pertain to the path stored in `$zip_processing_file` (which contains `Users`  and `Upload`) so that may be a separate issue.

However, the `require_once` issue may be due to the fact that your code isn't interpolating the `$zip_processing_file` variable.

Change:

```
require_once "zip_processing_file";
```

To:

```
require_once $zip_processing_file;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you should give the physical address of the php.

Like: '/var/www/..../zip_processing_file.php';

Answer (score 0):

So, following your code, from this:

```
$path = $base_path . trim($row['company']) . '/Users/' . trim($row['name']) . '/Upload/';
$zip_processing_file = $path . 'zip.php';
```

You should be getting something like (depending on the contents of `$base_path`:

```
/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/company/Users/name/Upload/zip.php
```

Instead, you're error is printing:

```
/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/Mail-test/
```

which doesn't make sense according to your code.

You need to make sure that the contents of $zip_processing_file contains the FULL server path to the PHP file you're needing to load.

The reason that the `header()` function worked is because it can take a web-root relative path. When using `require()` or any other file-based operation in PHP it must receive a document-relative path or a server-root path.

Comment: I just tried that as well.  Changed the FULL path for the $zip_processing_file.  It now will process my Cron job, doesn't give me any errors, but now it seems to stop at my zip.php file.  zip.php script isn't run.

Comment: What does the contents of your zip.php file look like? Does it have executable permissions? Is there a function you need to call or a class to instantiate?

Comment: Yes there is a class that I am calling: class dUnzip2.  I also am using fopen to read the contents of 2 .txt files.  Yes zip.php has 0777 permissions for testing.

Comment: Is dUnzip2 actually being called? I would start using exit() or mail() to find out where your script is stopping. Without seeing the whole code it's difficult to pinpoint the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want

```
require_once "/Mail-test/" . $zip_processing_file;
```